Tweepy : Twitter error response: status code = 403 : Troubleshooting Tweet Ingestion in Azure Solution Notebook (Spark)
I'm encountering a 403 error when ingesting tweets using Tweepy v3.10.0 and Twitter API. The Search API works fine in Postman, indicating an authentication issue within the notebook Ingest_Process_Tweets. Here is my the pipeline executed : Pipeline and the notebook correponding : Ingest_Process_Tweets.
The full error is as follows: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2907.throwExceptionIfHave. : com.microsoft.spark.notebook.msutils.NotebookExecutionException: Twitter error response: status code = 403
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue.
I've tried the Search API using Twitter's Postman Collection, and it works fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use Tweepy.Client for calling V2 API at X. Tweepy.API calls v1.1 API.

Thanks for the comment, that was indeed the problem. I was able to resolve it by using the client instead of the API and Bearer token for authentication.

@MarkusKauppinen I have encountered several challenges related to the Twitter API and compatibility issues between X v2 and Tweepy. Is it possible to use V1 ?

"Is it possible to use V1" Only for media upload and OAuth1.

Okay, thanks. So I have no choice but to use V2 with the stable version of tweepy, which is 14.4. In that case, can you tell me what I need to update in the Ingest_Process_Tweets file (in the description)  to comply with the new v4.14 standards, especially the data retrieval part?
